# heroku python3: ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Tags: python, heroku, encoding, python-3.4, reddit

I have been trying to get my [python3 reddit bot](https://gist.github.com/phikal/5b9461dc296221463102) to work on heroku for a while now, but I am encountering this error all the time:

```
~ $ python3
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This specifically happens when I run `python3` within a remote `bash` session ( via `heroku run bash` ).

`heroku logs` outputs:

```
2015-03-29T09:41:23.669871+00:00 heroku[bot.1]: Starting process with command `python3 allb.py`
2015-03-29T09:41:24.315878+00:00 heroku[bot.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-03-29T09:41:24.978050+00:00 app[bot.1]: Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
2015-03-29T09:41:24.978079+00:00 app[bot.1]: ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
2015-03-29T09:41:25.811735+00:00 heroku[bot.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2015-03-29T09:41:25.801807+00:00 heroku[bot.1]: Process exited with status 134
```

I have tried setting the runtime to 3.4, and looked for solutions, similar to the problem. Some sources said that `$PYTHONPATH` had to be nil, `$PYTHONPATH` on the heroku had the value `/app//`.

It's probably some stupid error, but I can't find it.

Comment: Any success with this in the end?

Comment: No, had to stop using heroku

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your python version in runtime.txt file.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes

Then on push you will see:

remote: -----> Found python-2.7.13, removing

remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.1